# Como puedo agregar libreria Itext en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

Tengo un error al importar Itext en Netbeans como puedo solucionarlo

```html
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontConstants;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFont;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import static com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.Font;
import static com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.FontFamily;


import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.border.Border;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;
import com.sun.javafx.geom.Rectangle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.text.normalizer.RangeValueIterator.Element;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado: [Importing library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402009/importing-library-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de Netbeans, debes crear un proyecto `Maven`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora selecciona el archivo `pom.xml` de tu proyecto ya que aquí es donde se agregarán las [dependencias necesarias](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrega las [**dependencías**](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7) dentro de `<project>  <dependencies>    <dependency>` y realiza un **Build** de tu proyecto!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar esto se descargarán los archivos .jar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora puedes agregar una clase a tu proyecto e importar las clases necesarias sin problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Prueba haciendo

1. click derecho en Bibliotecas
2. Agregar Archivo **JAR/Carpeta**
3. buscas el archivo **itext.jar**